# collection_select, undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added in the `@user = User.new` line to make sure it isn't nil. Which object is nil?

```
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #11):

8:  <%= f.hidden_field(:width)%>
9:  <%= f.hidden_field(:height)%>
10:     <% @user = User.new %>
11:     <%= collection_select(@user, :full_name, @user_array, :id, {:prompt => 'true'}, {:class=>'select'})%>
12:     <div class="submit-button">
13:         <%= submit_tag("Tag the person!")%>
14:     </div>
```

Comment: Instantiating a model in the view? Baaaaaaaaad!

Comment: Yep, I just included that line to make my debugging efforts clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@user_array` is `nil`. Make sure it's set with an array of users to avoid this error message.

Alternatively, set `@user_array` to `[]` (an empty array) if you wish to show no options in the `select,  e.g.:

```
collection_select @user, :full_name, @user_array || [], :id, 
  { prompt: 'true' }, { class: 'select' }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had meant to type @ users_array. This update line of code works:  <%= collection_select(@ tag, :user_id, @ users_array, :id, :full_name, {:class=>'select'})%>

Comment: I have similar problem, yes array is nil, but it is not supposed to be. I am creating an object in §create§ action, if it fails I'm am rendering current page to show error messages in the page, but my array is nil for some reason. In the action I am adding values to it, it shouldn't be nil. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You must to add @user_array to the actions: create, new, edit and update, the best way is using `before_actions`

```
before_action :set_user_array , only: [:edit, :update, :new, :create]

 private
    def set_user_array 
      @user_array = User.all 
    end
```